# Using Default Values and Spread Syntax in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-parameters, spread-syntax

While going through features of JavaScript, I used default arguments and spread syntax in same function.

```
let whatIsThis = (a, b = 2, ...c) => {
    console.log("a = " + a, "b = " + b,"c = " + c)
}

whatIsThis(a = 1, c = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

After running it, I expected output to be like this:

```
"a = 1"
"b = 2"
"c = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
```

But instead I got this:

```
"a = 1"
"b = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
"c = "
```

Why didn't this worked?

Comment: you can not address a parameter of a function by it's name. the names are not exposed to the outer scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you can't pass named arguments to a function in JavaScript. When you do whatIsThis(a = 1, c = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]) what it really means is whatIsThis(1, [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]) (because a = 1 statement returns 1).

What you can do is move default argument to the end (which is generally a good practice) or wrap your arguments in objects. For example

```
let whatIsThis = ({a, b = 2, c}) => {
    console.log("a = " + a, "b = " + b,"c = " + c)
}

whatIsThis({a: 1, c: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `undefined` for the second parameter and use [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for all other parameters of the function who are collected with [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

JavaScript does not have named parameters.

You need to hand over the parameters in the same order as the function signature.

```js
let whatIsThis = (a, b = 2, ...c) => {
  console.log("a = " + a, "b = " + b, "c = " + c)
}

whatIsThis(1, undefined, ...[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
//            ^^^^^^^^^                             takes default value
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   spreads values for rest parameters
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to use the spread syntax? I think `whatIsThis (1, undefined, [2,3,4,5,6,7,8])` will work fine.

Comment: @KaranDhir, it does, but you get a nested array (maybe wanted, maybe not).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call as `whatIsThis(a = 1, undefined , c = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8])` because you are using a default parameter in the middle of the function parameter so that should be called as `undefined` to use the default value.

```js
let whatIsThis = (a, b = 2, ...c) => {
    console.log("a = " + a, "b = " + b,"c = " + c)
}

whatIsThis(a = 1, undefined , c = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have *named arguments*. Arguments are assigned to parameters based only *by position*. You cannot assign arguments *by name* and you cannot simply skip the `b` argument. This:

```
whatIsThis(a = 1, c = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

Is equivalent to:

```
a = 1;
c = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
whatIsThis(a, c);
```

`a = 1` here is an assignment operation creating a new global variable; it has nothing to do with the parameter `a` of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the function parameter matters. In this case the the function order is `(a, b = 2, ...c)` but the function is called with only two parameters `whatIsThis(a = 1, c = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8])`.

So basically the argument `c` is undefined when the function is called and the parameter `b` refers to the array `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`.

Also note calling a function like this `whatIsThis(a = 1, c = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8])` will led some linting tools and IDE to throw error.